# Access to the path is deined

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, create-directory

I am trying to create a folder in my project and after the folder is create I want to save uploaded files in that folder. But it give me error message that Access to the path  is denied. 
Please tell me how to give permission to folder when I am creating that folder or any other solution for this 
Here is my code that I write

```
string fileName = FileUpload1.FileName;

    string path = "HotelImages/"+txthotelname.Text;
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    bool isExists=Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(path));
    if (!isExists)
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(path));
    }
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(path));
```

Please tell me where I am going wrong ?

Comment: Set the permission in the folder, instead in code. Grant Write permission to the user executing the asp.net page ( probably the IIS user )

Comment: The folder is creating dynamically how can i check it if my code is running and folder is creating I am creating the folder and after that i am saving the my images in that folder @ShivanRaptor

Comment: Add the right to the Application Pool of Your application to write the file system.